# Doubts for modeling with use cases

Tags: use-case

I'm practicing an exercise of use cases but it's hard for me know when it's ok or acceptable. The exercise it's about a system for sacrament of catholic churches and a part say

*The archbishopric requires that:*

*1) All baptism and weddings realized in catholic churches at province be registered in a central database* *which can be accessed from any catholic church (for realize the online documentation controls at the* *moment of give a turn)*

*2) Pcs of each church has to has internet connection. Each parish priest needs to have a user account with a password for access to system*

*3) Baptismal certificate and proof of marriage must be able to being printed according the official format* *of each type of certificate and been handed it over with independency of church where sacrament* was *celebrated*

*4) Know if there was a previous marriage and its actual state*
*Clarification: if girlfriend or boyfriend has a previous marriage but it was annulled or it’s windowed* *then it’s authorized for a new marriage*

*5) Know reasons by which marriage was annulated*

From this points I derivated this use cases:

1. Register Baptism, Consult Baptism, Register Marriages, Consult Marriages, Register Turn, Consult Turns, Modify Turns
2. Generate Sacrament Certificate
3. and 5) Consult Marriages

and actor Parish Priest, so my diagrame it's:

[image]

But I'm not sure how modeling the users of Parish Priests in point 2) and the print of the certificate in point 3) and I would like know what it's your opinion about the derivated use cases as far. Any advice  it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rule of thumb for creating use cases:**

> *As a [type of user], I want to [perform some action] so that I can [accomplish some result].*

Replace the text in each of the bracketed portions of the above template with meaningful words or phrases, and you should have a "valid" use case.

Create as many of these sentences as you need to fully encompass the desired behaviors of your candidate software system.

Answer (score 0):

#### To your question about #2:

Usually, for managing user accounts, there needs to be an administrator role - so the missing use case should be "manage user account" with the actor "administrator".

#### To your question about #3:

Why not model use cases "Print baptismal certificate" or "Print marriage certificate"?

#### What else?

I would also avoid to require the actor for these use cases to be a "Parish Priest", these use cases should be accessible by everyone who has a registered user account, and technically not require a very specific grade in church. So better model the actor as a "User", or "Full-access User".

For use cases like printing or querying information, where read-only access is sufficient, you may introduce another role like "Standard User".